# Accelerate: Finding pointer address for vDSP_maxviD

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, accelerate-framework

I am working on a machine learning project in `objective-c`. Which is using the following code:

```
unsigned cStride = multiArray.strides[2].intValue;
unsigned hStride = multiArray.strides[3].intValue;
unsigned wStride = multiArray.strides[4].intValue;

for (unsigned h = 0; h < height; h++) {
    for (unsigned w = 0; w < width; w++) {
        unsigned highestClass = 0;
        double highest = -DBL_MAX;
        for (unsigned c = 0; c < channels; c++) {
            unsigned offset = c * cStride + h * hStride + w * wStride;
            double score = pointer[offset];
            if (score > highest) {
                highestClass = c;
                highest = score;
            }
        }
        // futher code
    }
}
```

So far so good, it is working well. However I came across `Accelerate` which I want to implement for this class, since it could be faster then the current implementation.

I decided to implement `vDSP_maxviD`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1449682-vdsp_maxvid?language=objc

Their implementation is written as follows:

> __A Single-precision real input vector.
>
> __I Stride for A
>
> __C Output scalar
>
> __IC Output scalar index
>
> __N The number of elements to process

And their under the hood `Accelerate` code:

```
*C = -INFINITY;
for (n = 0; n < N; ++n)
{
    if (*C < A[n * I])
    {
        *C = A[n * I];
        *IC = n * I;
    }
}
```

Now I started to think what the parameters in this case need to become:

`__A` will become `pointer`

`__C` will become `highest`

`__IC` will become `highestClass`

`__N` will become `channels`

However, I left `__I` blank. This is because I don't know how to find the right `pointer` address. I my previous code I use:

`unsigned offset = c * cStride + h * hStride + w * wStride;`

However, we miss `c` now, and it's replaced by `n` inside the `Accelerate` framework.

What will be the correct calculation for my `pointer` index?

Comment: in your implementation the stride is different than the example. `cStride` vs `c * cStride + h * hStride + w * wStride`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **Grzegorz Owsiany** the final solution was:

```
double *channels_pointer = &pointer[h * hStride + w * wStride];
vDSP_maxviD(channels_pointer, cStride, &highest, &highestClass, channels);
```

However, I also needed to do:

```
highestClass /= cStride;
```

Answer (score 2):

problem is caused by using `pointer` as the first parameter of `vDSP_maxviD` ignoring `h` and `w` dependent offset.

try :

```
double *channels_pointer = &pointer[h * hStride + w * wStride];

vDSP_maxviD(channels_pointer, cStride, &highest, &highestClass, channels);
```

Comment: It works! However after the calculation we also need to do the following: `highestClass /= cStride;`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Removed unnecessary loop

I would try something like this (not tested):

```
uint32_t cStride = multiArray.strides[2].intValue;
uint16_t hStride = multiArray.strides[3].intValue;
uint8_t wStride = multiArray.strides[4].intValue;

for (uint16_t h = 0; h < height; h++) {
    for (uint16_t w = 0; w < width; w++) {
        uint8_t highestClass = 0;
        double highest = -DBL_MAX;
        //not sure about the type
        double * tempPointer = &pointer[h * hStride + w * wStride];
        vDSP_maxviD(tempPointer, cStride, &highest, &highestClass, channels);
        // further code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! However, using the third for-loop would be unnecessary, since `vDSP_maxviD` is one as well.